# paste 4 formulas in 4 columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm here today because i've got the task as trainee (ahum excel support/coffee maker) to find a way to put 4 different formulas and to apply them

For now i've tried to come up with one formula already but i've no idea if i go in the right direction :

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Detail")
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "F"), ws.Cells(lr, "F"))

       cell.Value="IF(H2="NB","",AY2)"

    Next cell
    End Sub
```

But i've this to basicly put and apply to 4 columns:

```
"MFR    CUSTLINE#   PRICE (DYP) DELIVERY
=IF(H2="NB","",AY2) =A2 =IF(P2="","NB",P2)  =IF(BR2>(D2+AM2),"STOCK",IF(AR2="0 Weeks","",SUBSTITUTE(AR2," Weeks"," WKS")))
"
```

The 4 MFR CUSTLINE PRICE and DELIVERY are just the overheads of the column so row 1 and then i've to apply the formula to the bottom of the column as i can have 5 rows or 15 000

Thanks in advance for your help and understanding as mine in vba or programming is basic if not less.

Comment: It is cell.Formula to enter a formula. And don't use cell as a variable name. Use something less ambiguous.

Comment: You can enter the formula in one go, no need to loop. What exactly is your problem - can't you just apply the formulae to each range?

Answer (score 2):

No loops needed:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Detail")

Dim lr As Long
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Dim arr
arr = Array("MFR", "CUSTLINE#", "PRICE (DYP)", "DELIVERY")
ws.Range("F1:I1").Value = arr

arr = Array("=IF(H2=""NB"","""",AY2)", "=A2", "=IF(P2="""",""NB"",P2)", "=IF(BR2>(D2+AM2),""STOCK"",IF(AR2=""0 Weeks"","""",SUBSTITUTE(AR2,"" Weeks"","" WKS"")))")
ws.Range("F2:I" & lr).Formula = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much  ! But i don't know why it goes why more down then it should my file stop for example row 50 and it goes to row 200 i changed it up a bit

`Sub azh()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Detail")

Dim lr As Long
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim arr
arr = Array("MFR", "CUSTLINE#", "PRICE (DYP)", "DELIVERY")
ws.Range("F1:I1").Value = arr

ty = Array("=IF(H2=""NB"","""",AY2)", "=A2", "=IF(P2="""",""NB"",P2)", "=IF(BR2>(D2+AM2),""STOCK"",IF(AR2=""0 Weeks"","""",SUBSTITUTE(AR2,"" Weeks"","" WKS"")))")
ws.Range("F2:I2" & lr).Formula = ty
End Sub`

Comment: then you have data in column A that goes to row 200.  Choose a different column maybe column H since that is what is referenced in the first formula.

Answer (score 1):

one way to go about it is:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Detail")
    Dim myRow As Long

    For myRow = 2 to ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("XA" & myRow).Formula = "=IF(H" & myRow & "=""NB"","""",AY" & myRow & ")"
        Range("XB" & myRow).Formula = "=A" & myRow
        Range("XC" & myRow).Formula = "=IF(P" & myRow & "="""",""NB"",P" & myRow & ")"
        Range("XD" & myRow).Formula = "=IF(BR" & myRow & ">(D" & myRow & "+AM" & myRow & "),""STOCK"",IF(AR" & myRow & "=""0 Weeks"","""",SUBSTITUTE(AR" & myRow & ","" Weeks"","" WKS"")))"
    Next myRow
End Sub
```

Note: this assumes the formulas are in columns `XA`, `XB`, `XC`, and `XD`

Edit: Fixed errant quote.

Comment: @Scott Craner: Well spotted! I am, as always, in your debt.